# jQuery Animation Queue And .stop(true)

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, drop-down-menu

First off - the end goal here is to create my own dropdown menu to learn jQuery.  If i move my mouse on and off of the nav buttons too fast, the animation queue gets built up and animations continue for several seconds after you stop.  I've found several forum threads that indicate **.stop(true)** is the solution to the jQuery animation queue buildup issues.  However, it doesn't seem to solve my issue when using multiple animations in a statement.

Here is the code (I've omitted the CSS.)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My First DropDown Menu</title>
<script language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css" />

<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div.bSlider ul li").hover(function() {
            $(this).stop(true, true).animate({ backgroundColor: "#898989", color: "#d01d33" }, 500, function() {}).find("ul").slideDown(200, function(){});
        }, function() {
            $(this).stop(true, true).animate({ backgroundColor: "#d01d33", color: "#ffc074"}, 0, function() {}).find("ul").slideUp(100, function(){});
        });
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="bSlider">
    <ul>
        <a href="#"><li>Menu Item #1</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Menu Item #2</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Menu Item #3</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Menu Item #4</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Menu Item #5
            <ul>
                <a href="#"><li>Sub-menu Item #1</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Sub-menu Item #2</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Sub-menu Item #3</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Sub-menu Item #4</li></a>
            </ul>
        </li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Menu Item #6</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an additional `.stop(true,true)` to stop the slidedown/up part.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/kZ78R/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.bSlider ul li").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({ backgroundColor: "#898989", color: "#d01d33" }, 500, function() {}).find("ul").stop(true,true).slideDown(200, function(){});
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({ backgroundColor: "#d01d33", color: "#ffc074"}, 0, function() {}).find("ul").stop(true,true).slideUp(100, function(){});
    });
});
```

Edit: Additional information

The reason you need a second `.stop()` is because `.stop()` only stops animations on the selected element, not it's children. Since the `<ul>` is a child of the selected element, it's animations were not stopped.